# How to force quit an AppleScript script launched from toolbar?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have an AppleScript script (to launch MySQL) that I run from the AppleScript toolbar menu. It does the job (launches MySQL), however the script doesn't seem to be quitting. And the gearwheel in the toolbar keeps rotating.

[image: Gearwheel keeps rotating]

When clicking the gearwheel I can click the 'x' close button for that script, but it does nothing. There are no frozen processes in Activity Monitor.

How can I "force quit" that script?

P.S. Someone asked what's the script, here it is:

```
do shell script "sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start" with administrator privileges
```

Comment: What's the script?

Comment: @Tetsujin I've added it to the question description.

Comment: OK, so you set it as a shell script - therefore it will wait until the app it launched quits, before moving on to the next line. I don't actually know how to prevent that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Stopping MySQL from System Preferences did not work. But I've quit a 'mysqld' process and the gearwheel disappeared.

Comment: I have some scripts that stay running for days, as the 'parent' of launched processes; at quit they then run further instructions to tidy up afterwards. I don't have them set as Services, so they don't annoy me by running that gear wheel.

Comment: Would you mind pointing me to how to set scripts so they don't run as Services?

Comment: Save the script as an App, launch by double-click. Mundane, but works for me ;) I'd wait to see if someone smarter than me knows how to make it step over, though - would be better long-term.

Comment: Find its PID and kill it

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first off, when you are using AppleScript’s “with administrator privileges” you should not use `sudo`

Second, you need to send the job into the background if you want the AppleScript to finish.

The easiest way of doing that is to put the command in a shell script, like so:

```
#!/bin/zsh -f

/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start &|

exit 0
```

*(Note the `&|` at the end of the line. That tells the process to go into the 'background')*

Save those 3 lines to a file named something like `/usr/local/bin/start-mysql-server.sh` and then do

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/start-mysql-server.sh
```

to make it executable.

Finally, change your AppleScript to

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/start-mysql-server.sh" with administrator privileges
```

and it *should* launch and then the gear should disappear.

Comment: how does it stop already running script ?

Comment: You'd need a separate script to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

1. Open terminal
2. Type `ps aux|grep mysql`
3. get the PID of the script
4. Type `kill -s 9 ####` where #### is the PID of the script

I would check to make sure that you don't kill the wrong process such as another mysql server.

Comment: you could use some smarts to check for the exact script you are running, but the above is very easily scriptable.

Comment: what is `-s 9`? Is is the same as `-9`?